# Which one is correct — "at the city" or "in the city"?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, prepositions, at-in

I want to know the correct preposition to use with the word *city* in the following context:

> - He arrived in the city.
> - He arrived at the city.

So which one will be correct?

Comment: Also see ["I am back to city" vs. "I am back in city"](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/70284),

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either one can be used, but we tend to use "in," because a city doesn't have a definitive border, but it does surround people.

Comment: Do you mean to say both these statements are correct? _1. Are you in New York?_ and _2. Are you at New York?_

Comment: To me, *at* would imply at the boundary. You might say that if you're at a port of some kind.